# Alternative to Actioncable in rails 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncable

I want to know which is the best alternative to develop Websockets in rails 4.2 since actioncable is only available for rails 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm [Plezi's](http://www.plezi.io) author, which leverages Iodine's implementation of [the Rack Websocket draft](https://github.com/boazsegev/iodine/blob/60eabf2cd0ac2a02ed905364de7762856c0d16e8/SPEC-Websocket-Draft.md), making it easy to use Websockets with Ruby applications.

Plezi can be used [as middleware within Rails](http://www.plezi.io/docs/with_rack_app), so you can get the best of both worlds.

Comment: You are very formal, it is a great help information, I congratulate you for supporting the development with ruby ​​on rails, I will study plezi, how can I implement it and tell you how I was, thank you very much

Comment: @Andres23Ramirez , cool, I'd love your feedback. I hope you enjoy the experience :)

Comment: Thankyou very much @Myst

Answer (score 2):

Actioncable available as separated gem. So it is not necessary to migrate to rails 5 to use Actioncable (if ignore other reason to migrate of course). So use:

```
gem 'actioncable'
```

Update: the code is still available on GitHub, if you can't get it anywhere else: https://github.com/rails/actioncable/tree/archive

Comment: Action Cable has been merged into Rails 5, Not available alone. This can be seen in the official github repository (https://github.com/rails/actioncable)

Comment: Have you tried? Is gem downloadable? Is gem worked? Check this: https://rubygems.org/gems/actioncable If the rails 4 is not very new then why not use a not very new gem.

Comment: I write this answer because I have read article before rails version 5 is appear. That article show how to use action cable in rails 4 with adding gem actioncable to Gemfile. I do not think that Applications created that time will not work today.

Comment: In the repository of github is not but in repository of rails gems yes, I will rehearse thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Find with which to solve my question, the gem faye is a good alternative to the one that you want to implement in your application the websocket, this is the link of the repo of github (https://github.com/faye/faye-websocket-ruby)